# Connecting to server failed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, connection

The following is my php code

```
<?
$server = 'mysql.hostinger.in';
$user = '*********';
$pass = '****';
$db = '********';
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $email;
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$in = "INSERT INTO Emails (Email)
VALUES ($email)";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

whenever I compile the code it gives me an error.

Comment: that isn't the only thing that's failing you, so is this `VALUES ($email)`

Comment: 1) [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. 2) failure to use quotes properly in your query.

Comment: What can i do to fix it?

Comment: +Fred -ii- What's the solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['your_submit_button_name'])){
$server = 'mysql.hostinger.in';
$user = '*********';
$pass = '****';
$db = '********';
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
echo $email;
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);
$in = "INSERT INTO `Emails` (Email) VALUES ('$email')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You must use isset function ([isset function](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php)) to send or do something with your form. Anyway, you must try to avoid sql problems.

Comment: +George but I have seen some demo codes long back as I remember and they didnt use Isset function

Comment: The fact that the `isset` was added dit not directly fix your issue - the missing quotes in your SQL did (quotes here: `VALUES ('$email')`), because `$email` is a string.